# Maximum call stack size exceeded error when using prisma $transaction

Tags: javascript, postgresql, prisma

this is my code in javaScript that uses prisma to work with postgreSQL database:

```
const updateCompany = async (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return next(
      new HttpError('Invalid inputs passed, please check your data.', 422),
    );
  }

  const companyId = req.params.id;
  const { name } = req.body;

  try {
    const company = await companyRepo.getCompanyById(companyId);

    if (!company) {
      return next(new HttpError('Company not found.', 404));
    }

    // Update company name
    company.name = name;    
    delete company.updatedAt;

    // Start the transaction
    const result = await prisma.$transaction(async (tx) => {
      const updatedCompany = await companyRepo.updateCompanyById(
        companyId,
        company,
        tx,
      );

      const companyWithSitesAndCranes =
        await companyRepo.getCompanyWithSitesAndCranesById(companyId, tx);

      // update each crane we got from the company
      const sites = companyWithSitesAndCranes.sites;
      for (const site of sites) {
        for (const crane of site.cranes) {
          await craneRepo.updateCraneById(crane.id, {
            identityName: `${updatedCompany.name}-${site.name}-${crane.name}`,
            tx,
          });
        }
      }

      return updatedCompany;
    });

    // // without transaction
    // const updatedCompany = await companyRepo.updateCompanyById(
    //   companyId,
    //   company,
    // );

    // const companyWithSitesAndCranes =
    //   await companyRepo.getCompanyWithSitesAndCranesById(companyId);

    // // update each crane we got from the company
    // const sites = companyWithSitesAndCranes.sites;
    // for (const site of sites) {
    //   for (const crane of site.cranes) {
    //     await craneRepo.updateCraneById(crane.id, {
    //       identityName: `${updatedCompany.name}-${site.name}-${crane.name}`,
    //     });
    //   }
    // }

    return res.status(200).json(result);
    // return res.status(200).json(updatedCompany);
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      err.message || 'Updating company failed.',
      err.code || 500,
    );
    next(error);
  }
};

const getCompanyWithSitesAndCranesById = (id, prismaClient = prisma) => {
  return prismaClient.company.findUnique({
    where: {
      id: id,
    },
    include: {
      sites: {
        include: {
          cranes: true,
        },
      },
    },
  });
};

const updateCompanyById = (id, company, prismaClient = prisma) =>
  prismaClient.company.update({ where: { id: id }, data: company });

const updateCraneById = (id, crane, prismaClient = prisma) => prismaClient.crane.update({ where: { id: id }, data: crane });
```

I wanted the updates to run in a transaction to make sure all the updates succeed.
My function worked fine when each query ran individually (without the transaction like in the commented part), but now when I run it, it gets stuck for around a minute until I get the following error:

Maximum call stack size exceeded  {
message: 'Maximum call stack size exceeded',
name: 'Error',
stack: 'Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded\n'
code: 500
}

I've searched this error and only found it regarding recursion functions...

Its important to note that I'm running it with an almost empty database so its not like there are a ton of updates caused by it.

I am using prisma version 9.8.1

Anybody got a clue on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) Do you have `UPDATE` triggers on the table(s)? 2) You have not shown what is actually going on inside the functions. Best bet is you have set up a recursion via a trigger firing and or the functions feeding off each other.

Comment: Each call of updateCraneById updates a single entry in the db like so:
const updateCraneById = (id, crane, prismaClient = prisma) =>
  prismaClient.crane.update({ where: { id: id }, data: crane });

thats it...the other parts don't do anything special, mostly a try-catch wrap and some input checks...

Comment: You have an infinite recursion somewhere in your code, probably in a part of the code that the question doesn't show. Find and fix that.

Comment: There is no recursion somewhere in my code...if i comment this part of the code or just run it without the transaction it executes in an instant and works just fine.

Comment: 1) You have not answered whether there are triggers on  the table. 2) Add the code for `updateCraneById` as properly formatted text to the question text. 3) Comment what part of the code? 4) Pretending this *{ message: 'Maximum call stack size exceeded', name: 'Error', stack: 'Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded\n' code: 500 }* is not a thing will not solve the issue.

Comment: I updated to post to include the full function and the implementations of the actual prisma queries. It also includes the non-transaction version that doesn't get the error as a commented block titled "without transaction".
In regards to your first question, there are no triggers defined on the tables.
Lastly I am not sure what you meant in your "4)" comment.